# JMeter script recording / playback issues

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to create a script using jmeter (V2.13).  If I look at the results in the "View Results Tree", and all the request/response pairs are green, but the script is not working.  I start to see "404" errors in the responses, and after a while, I just see the same responses being reported, over and over again.  Not sure how to debug something like this.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks..Tom

Answer (score 0):

Recording through JMeter (or any other tool) is not enough, you need after that to do some correlation work:

- Extract ids from some responses and inject them in next requests
- Variabilize some data to put them in CSV (login , password ...)
- Add timers
- Add assertions to check

Answer (score 0):

You must be seeing 404 for Images and other resources. You need to clean your JMeter script before you plan to replay it. You need to add cookie manager in order to manage the sessions if any sessions are being created by your script.

If the script isnt reflecting expected results you need to correlate Dynamic variables being created. in order to understand what all variables are changing for each run, compare the recorded parameters with actual requests being sent from browser. You can achieve this either by using developer tools or some network sniffing tool like Fiddler or Wireshark. Once you know what all Dynamic values are being passed either use Postprocessor-Regular Expression Extractor or Beanshell PostProcessor and pass these values to further requests.

Once you have correlated everything you should be able to see the changes. Also dont forget to add Assertions to verify correctness of the response and Timers/Test Action to add delays/Think Time.